# Does orientation of code affect result?

Tags: javascript, html, jsbin

I wrote this code in jsbin. Here is the [link](http://jsbin.com/jewegomice/edit?html,css,js,output). I wrote the code like this :

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="elem" onclick="clone()">  
  </div></div>
```

Then I pressed enter before the last < /div >. The code became like this :

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="elem" onclick="clone()">  
  </div>
</div><!-- ONLY THIS LINE WAS CHANGED -->
```

After I pressed enter before the last < /div >, the code doesn't work anymore! This really confuses me. How can that happen?

Comment: Are you sure something else didn't change somewhere else on the page?

Comment: Yes, it does. `lastChild` finds the last node, including white-space charcters and new-lines in the source code. Use `lastElementChild` if you want to refer HTMLElements only.

Answer (score 0):

This is [**Teemu**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu)**'s** answer :

lastChild finds the last node, including white-space characters and new-lines in the source code.
Use lastElementChild to refer HTML elements only.